# Get the value from form while clicking on submit

Tags: clojurescript

```clj
(defn text-input
  [label]
  [:div.row
   [:div.col-md-2
    [:span label]]
   [:div.col-md-3
    [:input {:type "text" :class "form-control" :style {:border "1px solid red"}}]]])


(defn hello-world
  []
  [:div.page-header
   [:h1 "Reagent Form"]
   [text-input "First name" ]
   [text-input "last name"]
   [text-input "mobile number"]
   [text-input "address"]
   [:button {:type "submit" :class "btn btn-default"
             :on-click #(.log js/console (clj->js @state))} "Submit"] ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the value from the event you can use an on-click handler like this:

```
(fn [event] (.log js/console (-> event .-target .-value)))
```

So use that instead of `#(.log js/console (clj->js @state))`.

See http://reagent-project.github.io/ for examples of using the target value. E.g.,

[image: Example input]

```
(ns example
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))

(defn atom-input [value]
  [:input {:type "text"
           :value @value
           :on-change #(reset! value (-> % .-target .-value))}])

(defn shared-state []
  (let [val (r/atom "foo")]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:p "The value is now: " @val]
       [:p "Change it here: " [atom-input val]]])))
```